# Calculating max field goal percentage in a method in java program

Tags: java

Have to find both max and min in a set of data of a team's field goal percentage.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class kstatebball
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("data1.txt"));
        String[] firstname = new String [100];
        String[] lastname = new String [100];
        int fgm[] = new int [100];
        int fga[] = new int [100];
        double fgp = 0;        
        int maxFGP;
        int minFGP;              

        System.out.print("         Player              FGM     FGA             FGP%\n");
        int  count = 0;
        for( int i = 0;in.hasNext(); i++)
        {
            firstname[i] = in.next(); 
            lastname[i] = in.next();
            fgm[i] = in.nextInt();
            fga[i] = in.nextInt();
            fgp = (1.0 * fgm[i]) / (1.0 * fga[i]) * 100;
            count++;           
            System.out.printf("%10s %10s        %3d     %3d             %3.1f  \n",firstname[i],lastname[i],fgm[i],fga[i],fgp);            
        }
        maxFGP = maxFGP(fgm,fga,count);
        minFGP = minFGP(fgm,fga,count);
        System.out.printf("\n\nThe player with the highest field goal percentage is: %3d ",maxFGP(fgm,fga,count));
        System.out.printf("\nThe player with the lowest field goal percentage is : %3.1f",fgp);
    }

    public static int maxFGP(int[] fgm, int[] fga, int count)
    {
        int max = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if((1.0 * fgm[i]) / (1.0 * fga[i]) * 100 > max) 
                max = i;            
        }
        return max;
    }



    public static int minFGP(int[]fgm, int[]fga, int count)
    {
        int min = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i > 13; i++)
        {
            if(fgm[i] > fgm[count])
                count = i;            
        }
        return min;
    }        
}
```

Need help with the "if" statement for it to return the correct max.

We have our percentages for all of the players, but need to use the methods in order to find the player with the greatest field goal percentage and also the lowest.

Here's the data file I am using:

```
Marcus Foster    123   288
Thomas Gipson    102   178
Shane Southwell  88    224
Will Spradling   58    144
Wesley Iwundu    53    111
Nino Williams    49    96
Nigel Johnson    28    80
Jevon Thomas     15    58
D.J. Johnson     34    68
Omari Lawrence   27    65
Shawn Meyer      2     4
Ryan Schultz     2     9
Jack Karapetyan  1     4
Brian Rohleder   1     2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be like this:

```
public static int maxFGP(int[] fgm, int[] fga, int count)
{
    int max = 0;
    double maxValue=(1.0 * fgm[0]) / (1.0 * fga[0]) * 100;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if((1.0 * fgm[i]) / (1.0 * fga[i]) * 100 > maxValue)                                                      
        {
            max = i;  
            maxValue=(1.0 * fgm[i]) / (1.0 * fga[i]) * 100;  
        }        
    }
    return max;
}
```

note: you already set `int max = 0;` so no need to loop from `i=0`. change `int i=1` instead

To print the **name** of the player with max value:

```
System.out.printf("\n\nThe player with the highest field goal percentage is: %3d ",firstname[maxFGP(fgm,fga,count)]);
```

Comment: it's still just printing a 13 for the highest percent. we need to remain the max value of an int

Comment: @Tanner11 `13` is the `index` of the max value. what you would like to print actually?

Comment: the player with the 57.3%. I am trying to print out the player who has the highest field goal percentage

Comment: I added the data file I am using

Comment: @Tanner11 if you want to print the name, then print `System.out.println(firstname[maxFGP(fgm,fga,count)])`

Comment: ok I have it printing a name now, but it is the wrong one. it is printing "Brian" when it should be "Gipson"

Comment: @Tanner11 yes. my bad. change to `if((1.0 * fgm[i]) / (1.0 * fga[i]) * 100 > maxValue) `

Comment: yes i changed it to a greater and still has same result

Comment: I just got the max to work, but still have the min wrong... here's what I changed in the max

Comment: @Tanner11 ok, check back the updated answer. you are welcome :)

Comment: if(((1.0 * fgm[i]) * 100) / (1.0 * fga[i]) * 100 > max)

Comment: Any reason why you think my "min" isn't working? It is coming out with  Foster instead of Schultz. I changed the signs to it

Comment: @Tanner11 change your `minFGP()` method exactly like the `maxFGP()` just modify the `>` to `<`

Answer (score 0):

`max` is an array index, I would suggest you add another another method to calculate the percentage

```
public static int maxFGP(int[] fgm, int[] fga, int count)
{
    int max = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < count; i++){
        if(fieldGoalPercentage(fgm, fga, i) > fieldGoalPercentage(fgm, fga, max)) 
            max = i;            
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java's an object oriented language.  You're probably a beginner, but here's another way to think about it.

Start with a Player object:

```
package misc;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * misc.Player
 * @author Michael
 * @link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21843505/calculating-max-field-goal-percentage-in-a-method-in-java-program
 * @since 2/17/14 10:07 PM
 */
public class Player {

    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final int numAttempts;
    private final int numMakes;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Player> team = new ArrayList<Player>() {{
            add(new Player("Larry", "Bird", 40, 80));
            add(new Player("Robert", "Parish", 4, 10));
            add(new Player("Dennis", "Johnson", 35, 50));
        }};
        System.out.println("before sort: " + team);
        Collections.sort(team, new Comparator<Player>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Player that, Player other) {
                if (that.getFieldGoalPercentage() < other.getFieldGoalPercentage()) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (that.getFieldGoalPercentage() > other.getFieldGoalPercentage()) {
                    return +1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });
        System.out.println("after  sort: " + team);
    }

    public Player(String firstName, String lastName, int numMakes, int numAttempts) {
        this.firstName = (isBlank(firstName) ? "" : firstName);
        this.lastName = (isBlank(lastName) ? "" : lastName);
        this.numAttempts = (numAttempts < 0 ? 0 : numAttempts);
        this.numMakes = (numMakes < 0 ? 0 : numMakes);
        if (this.numMakes > this.numAttempts) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("number of makes %d cannot exceed number of attempts %d", numMakes, numAttempts));
        }
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public int getNumAttempts() {
        return numAttempts;
    }

    public int getNumMakes() {
        return numMakes;
    }

    public double getFieldGoalPercentage() {
        double fieldGoalPercentage = 0.0;
        if (this.numAttempts > 0) {
            fieldGoalPercentage = ((double) numMakes)/numAttempts;
        }
        return fieldGoalPercentage;
    }

    public static boolean isBlank(String s) {
        return ((s == null) || (s.trim().length() == 0));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Player player = (Player) o;

        return firstName.equals(player.firstName) && lastName.equals(player.lastName);

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = firstName.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + lastName.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("misc.Player{");
        sb.append("firstName='").append(firstName).append('\'');
        sb.append(", lastName='").append(lastName).append('\'');
        sb.append(", numAttempts=").append(numAttempts);
        sb.append(", numMakes=").append(numMakes);
        sb.append(", percentage=").append(getFieldGoalPercentage());
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```